# Accessing router memory

Tags: memory-management, hardware, router

This question might be stupid because I'm completely oblivious to how hardware functions.

My question is the following :

- How can you access a routers memory (on the software side) ?

By memory, I don't mean routing tables or DNS cache but a real "disk".

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will vary from device to device.  Most of the *nix varieties have a simple filesystem that you can mount in read/write mode to write to the on-board flash.

Comment: by " *nix varieties " do you mean the more "professional" routers like Cisco and so on that have their own distro ?

Comment: Cisco has its own OS entirely... Cisco IOS.  Many of the cheaper routers actually are typically Linux.  Linksys WRT54g and similar, for example.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer I will "check mark" it when it will be allowed (in 5min).

Answer (score 1):

option 1: you mount it if you can, (if it is a linux based router or a commercial router hardware which gives running script privg.) after that normal r/w operations.

option 2: you may try ssh or telnet. (for ex, i'm using telnet on axis ip cameras)

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure what you mean by a real "disk". Do you mean the routers that allow you to plug in an external hard drive?

I might be wrong but I would suspect that not all (if any) would allow such access. I think this will depend entirely on what router you are going to be using. I suspect every manufacturer/model would have their own methods.

Comment: Oh sorry, by "disk" I meant a filesystem for the router.